# how to spam an email using VBS

Tags: email, vbscript

So i would like to spam an email to check the spam filters. However, it keeps giving me error messages. Such as

> could not connect to STMP server

Please help me to improve this.

```
Dim User
Dim Pass
Dim Name
Dim Input
Dim Input2
Dim Input3
X=MsgBox("Welcome. To log in Please Click OK and enter your G-mail & pass.",0,"EmailSpamBot V1.0")
User = InputBox("Enter your G-mail:")
Pass = InputBox("Enter Password:"& vbCrLf & ""& vbCrLf & "Please note passwords are NOT stored in this script and are case sensitive.")
Name = InputBox("Enter Name:")
Input = InputBox("Enter e-mail of victim:")
Input2 = InputBox("Enter title:")
Input3 = InputBox("Enter message:")
EmailSubject = (""& Input2)
EmailBody = (""& Input3)

'Const EmailFrom = ""
'Const EmailFromName = ""

Const SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
'Const SMTPLogon = ""
'Const SMTPPassword = ""
Const SMTPSSL = True
Const SMTPPort = 465

Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1  'Send message using local SMTP service pickup directory.
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2  'Send the message using SMTP over TCP/IP networking.

Const cdoAnonymous = 0  ' No authentication
Const cdoBasic = 1  ' BASIC clear text authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2  ' NTLM, Microsoft proprietary authentication

' First, create the message

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = EmailSubject
objMessage.From = "<" & User & Name & ">"
objMessage.To = "<" & Input & ">"
objMessage.TextBody = EmailBody

' Second, configure the server

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTPServer

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = User

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = Pass

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = SMTPPort

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = SMTPSSL

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

do
ObjMessage.Send 
loop
```

Any help would be greatly appreciatied

Comment: I get different error `Error: The message could not be sent to the SMTP server. The transport error code was 0x80040217. The server response was not available`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "could not connect to SMTP server" means that your script couldn't establish a connection to the given port on the remote host. That usually happens when a firewall is blocking access. You can verify that with the `telnet` command:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
```

If access is blocked you should be getting output like this after the timeout expiered:

> Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 465: Connect failed

A tool like [`tracetcp`](http://simulatedsimian.github.io/tracetcp.html) might provide further insight as to where the packets are blocked.

However, sending authenticated mail is normally for outbound message submission. If you want to test your own spam filter, you should be sending inbound mail (to port 25).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, when you enter your email, five minutes or so later you get a security email about a less secure app attempting to access, that is the VBS script, you click on the enable less secure app access, and then it works.